# MySQL and Doctrine QueryBuilder Multiple LEFT and INNER JOINS from three tables

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony

I am using Symfony 3 and doctrine 2.5. There's three tables total:

```
 a. user table:
      id     name
       1     Alex
       2     Jim
       3     Bob

 b. companies table
      id     name
       1     company1
       2     company2

 c. company_users containing the relationship, both user_id and company_id.
      id     company_id   user_id
       1     1            1
       2     2            1
       3     2            2
```

Given company id 2, Final result should be this, but for the life of me I cannot write a working Doctrine QueryBuilder method for it

```
1   company2 - Alex
2   company2 - Jim
```

I have three working MySQL queries that bring me the desired result.
BUT for the life of me I cannot transpose any of it into at least one working Doctrine query.

Working MySQL queries (which maybe will actually help some users around here):

```
SELECT companies.name, user.username
FROM companies
LEFT JOIN company_users ON company_users.company_id = companies.id
LEFT JOIN user ON company_users.user_id = user.id WHERE companies.id = 2;

SELECT u.username, c.name
FROM user u, company_users cu, companies c
WHERE cu.user_id = u.id and cu.company_id = c.id and c.id = 2

SELECT companies.name, user.username
FROM companies
LEFT JOIN company_users
    INNER JOIN user
    ON company_users.user_id=user.id
ON company_users.company_id=companies.id WHERE companies.id=2;
```

My attempt at Doctrine's QueryBuilder:

```
        ->select('u.username', 'c.name')
        ->from('companies','c')
        ->leftJoin('c', 'company_users', 'cu', 'company_users.company_id = companies.id')
        ->leftJoin('u', 'user', 'u', 'company_users.user_id = user.id')
        ->where('c.id = :companyId')
        ->setParameter('companyId', $companyId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: Why don't you use aliases in join conditions? `'company_users.company_id = companies.id'` -> `'cu.company_id = c.id'`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use aliases in join conditions? `'company_users.company_id = companies.id'` -> `'cu.company_id = c.id'`.

Left join syntax differs from one that you use.

> public function leftJoin($join, $alias, $conditionType = null,
>   $condition = null, $indexBy = null);

Fixed builder

```
->select('u.username', 'c.name')
    ->from('companies','c')
    ->leftJoin('company_users', 'c', 'WITH', 'cu.company_id = c.id')
    ->leftJoin('user', 'u', 'WITH', 'cu.user_id = u.id')
    ->where('c.id = :companyId')
    ->setParameter('companyId', $companyId)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper answer that worked for Symfony 3 and doctrine 2.5's queryBuilder.

```
$query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('u.username', 'c.name', 'c.id')
        ->from('AppBundle\Entity\User','u')
        ->leftJoin('AppBundle\Entity\CompanyUsers', 'cu', 'WITH', 'cu.user = u.id')
        ->leftJoin('AppBundle\Entity\Companies', 'c', 'WITH', 'cu.company = c.id')
        ->where('u.id = :userId')
        ->setParameter('userId', $userId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    $result = [];
    $result['userName'] = $query[0]['username'];
    $result['userId'] = $userId;
    $result['companies'] = [];

    foreach ($query as $q) {
        $result['companies'][] = array('companyName' => $q['name'], 'companyId' => $q['id']);

    }

    return $result;
```